# How can I improve performance with FutureTasks

Tags: multithreading, cpu, processor, futuretask

The problem seems simple, I have a number (huge) of operations that I need to work and the main thread can only proceed when all of those operations return their results, however. I tried in one thread only and each operation took about let's say from 2 to 10 seconds at most, and at the end it took about 2,5 minutes. Tried with future tasks and submited them all to the ExecutorService. All of them processed at a time, however each of them took about let's say from 40 to 150 seconds. In the end of the day the full process took about 2,1 minutes.

If I'm right, all the threads were nothing but a way of execute all at once, although sharing processor's power, and what I thought I would get would be the processor working heavily to get me all the tasks executed at the same time taking the same time they take to excecuted in a single thread.

Question is: Is there a way I can reach this? (maybe not with future tasks, maybe with something else, I don't know)

Detail: I don't need them to exactly work at the same time that actually doesn't matter to me what really matters is the performance

Answer (score 0):

You might have created way too many threads. As a consequence, the cpu was constantly switching between them thus generating a noticeable overhead.

You probably need to limit the number of running threads and then you can simply submit your tasks that will execute concurrently.

Something like:

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);
List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>(runnables.size());
for(Runnable r : runnables) {
    es.submit(r);
}
// wait they all finish:
for(Future<?> f : futures) {
    f.get();
}
// all done
```